# Why does my $PATH show anaconda and other weird things in it?

Tags: macos, path, anaconda

When I go on my Mac's Terminal and type `echo $PATH I get:

> /anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

whereas most other people online have something like

> usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

or something along those lines.

I did install the anaconda application, but I'm scared I screwed something up on my mac or my installations and that this will interfere with future projects.

Does anyone know why I get what I get, what it means, if I should be concerned, and how to fix it if it needs to be fixed?

Comment: Here's a good place to start learning about what PATH is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest that you read about what `PATH` means and how it is used by the shell. The short answer is no, you don't need to be worried. In fact, these are a convenience that allow you to easily use anaconda tools from the command line.